# How to get count record for every month for year from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried this code, it's returning all records with month name, but without total count

```
SELECT 
    DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH([R_datetime]), -1 )) MonName,
    COUNT(*) count 
FROM 
    [Tbl_TechRequest]
WHERE 
    ([R_datetime]) BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
                       AND DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1)    
GROUP BY  
    [R_datetime]
```

Comment: Your group by is off

Comment: Ah yes. @scsimon is correct. Group By the `Month` that you are getting the counts for.

Comment: And please have a look into MCVEs, [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and [how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes i was missing group by for month it work fine now .  thank you for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, R_datetme),
    DATEPART(month, R_datetime),
    count (*) 
from myTable
where
    [R_datetime])  > = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) 
group by 
    DATEPART(year, R_datetme), 
    DATEPART(month, R_datetime)
```

OR

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(year, R_datetme)*100 + DATEPART(month, R_datetime),
    count(*) 
from myTable
where
    [R_datetime])  > = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, -1) 
group by 
    DATEPART(year, R_datetme)*100 + DATEPART(month, R_datetime)
```

Comment: You still need the where clause from the OP